# Configuring remember me facility in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

RememberMeConfigurer uses UserDetailsService by calling its method loadUserByUsername(),
the problem is, I want it to pass user's email and not username.
It works with simple login, but not with remember me option.
How can I make remember me facility to pass email (not username) to UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername()?
login form:

```
<form action="login" method="POST" >

              <legend>Sing In</legend>

              <div class="form-group">

                <div class="input-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="email">
                    Email
                  </label>

                  <div class="form-input-field">

                      <input id="email" name="username"
                             type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="form-group">

                <div class="input-group">
                  <label class="form-label" for="password">
                    Password
                  </label>

                  <div class="form-input-field">

                      <input id="password" name="password"
                             type="password" autocomplete="off" />
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">
                <label id="checkbox-label" class="form-label" for="remember">
                  Remember me
                </label>

                <div class="form-input-field">

                    <input id="remember" name="remember"
                           type="checkbox" />
                </div>

              </div>

              <div id="submit-button">

                  <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />

              </div>

      </form>
```

WebSecurityConfiguration:

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity.formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/account")
                    .and()
                        .rememberMe()
                        .key("rem-me-key")
                        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                        .rememberMeParameter("remember")
                        .rememberMeCookieName("rememberMeCookie")
                        .tokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60 * 24 * 3)
                    .and()
                        .logout()
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .permitAll();

        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                    .mvcMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .mvcMatchers("/account").hasRole("CUSTOMER")
                    .mvcMatchers("/cart").hasRole("CUSTOMER")
                    .anyRequest().permitAll();


        httpSecurity.csrf()
                    .disable();

    }
```

UserDetailsService impl:

```
@Service
public class AppUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private static final Logger log =
            LogManager.getLogger(AppUserDetailsService.class.getName());

    private AppUserRetrievalRepository appUserRetrievalRepository;

    public AppUserDetailsService(
            @Autowired
            AppUserRetrievalRepository appUserRetrievalRepository) {

        this.appUserRetrievalRepository = appUserRetrievalRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        log.info("Trying to load user by name: " + email);

        Optional<AppUser> optUser =
                appUserRetrievalRepository.getUserByEmail(email);

        UserDetails userDetails =
                new AppUserDetails(optUser.orElseThrow(
                        () -> new UsernameNotFoundException(email + " cannot be found") )
                );

        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

The logs showing the problem:
~When I use login without remember me option checked:

```
*** LOG4J *** Trying to load user by name: myEmailAddress@example.com
```

~When I use login with remember me option checked:

```
*** LOG4J *** Trying to load user by name: cody
```

Comment: `I want it to pass user's email and not username. It works with simple login, but not with remember me option.` I dont understand your question. Please write more in detail, with debugging logs that shows the problem.

Comment: The email address is thus the username and your `UserDetails` implementation should reflect that.

Comment: I did so. If I get it right, the problem is that after successful authentication, RememberMeConfigurer uses loadByUsername() method to get the user and create a cookie. It would be all good if it passed email (myEmailAddress@example.com), but it passes username(cody).

Comment: Because, I assume, that your `AppUserDetails` doesn't properly return the emailaddress as the username which it should.

Comment: Yeah, It worked. Thank you M. Deinum!